# Convert XML to String and append to page

Tags: javascript, xml, xml-serialization

I want to convert an xml element like this:

```js
<asin>​B0013FRNKG​</asin>​
```

to string in javascript

I used `XMLSerializer`:

```js
new XMLSerializer().serializeToString(xml);
```

the string only shows on alert() and in the console. On the page it just says

```js
[object Element][object Element]
```

I want to get the string.

Comment: do you want to get `"<asin>​B0013FRNKG​</asin>​"`, or `"B0013FRNKG"`?

Answer (score 53, accepted):

You haven't told us how you go about displaying that object. XMLSerializer works on DOM nodes, so your object has to be added somewhere, for example:

```js
document.getElementById('SomeDiv').appendChild(xml);
```

and if you just want the full xml string to be displayed:

```js
var xmlText = new XMLSerializer().serializeToString(xml);
var xmlTextNode = document.createTextNode(xmlText);
var parentDiv = document.getElementById('SomeDiv');
parentDiv.appendChild(xmlTextNode);
```

Comment: This worked! Thank you. I didnt know about the `createTextNode` part. I thought XML could be used like JSON.

Answer (score 7):

```
<script type='text/javascript'>

    function xmlToString(xmlData) { 

        var xmlString;
        //IE
        if (window.ActiveXObject){
            xmlString = xmlData.xml;
        }
        // code for Mozilla, Firefox, Opera, etc.
        else{
            xmlString = (new XMLSerializer()).serializeToString(xmlData);
        }
        return xmlString;
    }   

</script>
```

use this in case of IE for browser compatibility issues.

Comment: I've been using exactly this code for a while but I've come across a client running IE10 in Win7.  They have "use natvie XMLHTTP" checked in Internet Options (not that that is relevant in this case).  However "window.ActiveXObject" evaluates to truthy but xmlData.xml returns *undefined*.  Any idea why?

Answer (score 4):

```javascript
function getXmlString(xml) {
  if (window.ActiveXObject) { return xml.xml; }
  return new XMLSerializer().serializeToString(xml);
}
alert(getXmlString(xml));
```

Answer (score 3):

Did you try enclosing the result like in…

```
(new XMLSerializer()).serializeToString(xml)
```

Also, I'd use console instead to see the content better:

```
console.log((new XMLSerializer()).serializeToString(xml));
```

Answer (score 0):

If the DOM element `<asin>​B0013FRNKG​</asin>​` is stored in the object `element`, then you can access the value using:

```
element.textContent
```

Answer (score 0):

follow this to print,append data from xml data stored as string inside javscript

```
txt="<papers>"+"<paper>"+
 "<author>athor name</author>"+
"<title>title</title>"+
"<path>path</path>"+
"<track>which tack</track>"+
 "</paper>"+
"<paper>"+
"<author>athor name</author>"+
"<title>title</title>"+
"<path>path</path>"+
"<track>which tack</track>"+
"</paper>"+
"<paper>"+
"<author>athor name</author>"+
"<title>title</title>"+
"<path>path</path>"+
"<track>which tack</track>"+
"</paper>"+
"<papers>";
if (window.DOMParser)
  {
      parser=new DOMParser();
  xmlDoc=parser.parseFromString(txt,"text/xml");

   }
   else // Internet Explorer
    {
     xmlDoc=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLDOM");
     xmlDoc.async=false;
     xmlDoc.loadXML(txt);
    }

x=xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("paper"); 
for (var i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {  
    var athor =x[i].childNodes[0].firstChild.nodeValue;
    var title = x[i].childNodes[1].firstChild.nodeValue;
    var path = x[i].childNodes[2].firstChild.nodeValue;
    var tack =x[i].childNodes[3].firstChild.nodeValue;
    //do something with these values...
    //each iteration gives one paper details    
    var xml=document.getElementById("element_id");//<div id="element_id"></div>
    var li = document.createElement("br");// create a new <br>  
    newlink = document.createElement('A'); // creating an <a> element
    newlink.innerHTML = athor;// adding <a>athor value here</a>
    newlink.setAttribute('href', path);// <a href="path"></a>

    newlink.appendChild(li);// <a href="path">athor</a><br>
    document.getElementById("element_id").appendChild(newlink);//finaly it becomes <div id="element_id"><a href="path">athor</a><br></div>


}
```