# Read XML file using JavaScript in Chrome

Tags: javascript, xml, xmldom

I need to load and read an XML file using JavaScript.

The following code works fine in Firefox, IE and Opera:

```js
function loadXMLDoc(dname) {
  var xmlDoc

  // Internet Explorer
  try {
    xmlDoc = new ActiveXObject('Microsoft.XMLDOM')
  }
  catch (e) {
    // Firefox, Opera, etc.
    try {
      xmlDoc = document.implementation.createDocument('', '', null)
    }
    catch (e) {
      alert(e.message)
    }
  }

  try {
    xmlDoc.async = false
    xmlDoc.load(dname)
    return xmlDoc
  }
  catch (e) {
    alert(e.message)
  }

  return null
}
```

But executing this code in Chrome gives me this error:

> Object# has no method "load"

Comment: Is it not just `loadXML` instead of `load`?

Comment: Hi @putvande..thank you for response me, i can't get from you? Loadxml is just function which take from w3school website.my problem is chrome browser will not working fine.. any idea for my problem?

Comment: Why use XMLDocument object instead of DOMParser/Microsoft.XMLDOM? You can load the xml text with an xhmlhttp request.

Comment: Hi @HMR..I got your point..I am newbie in xml parsing functionality.I searching XML DOM only..I had much more knowledge in Dom-parser.can you give some idea for me? It will more helpful for me

Comment: Hi @HMR..Any idea about this ? Please some responsible comment from you.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

## Legacy Code

`document.implementation.createDocument` does not work on Chrome and Safari.

Use `XMLHttpRequest` instead when possible:

```js
function loadXMLSync(url) {
  try {
    // Prefer XMLHttpRequest when available
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest()
    xhr.open('GET', url, false)
    xhr.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'text/xml')
    xhr.send()

    return xhr.responseXML
  }
  catch (e) {
    // XMLHttpRequest not available, fallback on ActiveXObject
    try {
      var activex = new ActiveXObject('Microsoft.XMLDOM')
      activex.async = false
      activex.load(url)

      return activex
    }
    catch (e) {
      // Neither XMLHttpRequest or ActiveXObject are available
      return undefined
    }
  }
}
```

---

## Modern Browsers

If you're targeting modern browsers (> IE6), just use XMLHttpRequest:

```js
function loadXMLSync(url) {
  var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest()

  xhr.open('GET', url, false)
  xhr.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'text/xml')
  xhr.send()

  return xhr.responseXML
}
```

Comment: isn't ActiveXObject deprecates for modern browsers?

Answer (score 1):

On MDN, there is guidance to use XMLHttpRequest. But it isn't clear from DOMImplementation.createDocument until you drill into the return type and see that [XMLDocument](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLDocument) is not supported in Google Chrome. The [example on W3Schools](http://www.w3schools.com/dom/dom_loadxmldoc.asp) uses XMLHttpRequest.

Answer (score 0):

follow this to print,load,append xml data.Here xml is stored as string inside javascript.This method works in chrome,firefox hopes it will work in others too

```
txt="<papers>"+"<paper>"+
 "<author>athor name</author>"+
"<title>title</title>"+
"<path>path</path>"+
"<track>which tack</track>"+
 "</paper>"+
"<paper>"+
"<author>athor name</author>"+
"<title>title</title>"+
"<path>path</path>"+
"<track>which tack</track>"+
"</paper>"+
"<paper>"+
"<author>athor name</author>"+
"<title>title</title>"+
"<path>path</path>"+
"<track>which tack</track>"+
"</paper>"+
"<papers>";
if (window.DOMParser)
  {
      parser=new DOMParser();
  xmlDoc=parser.parseFromString(txt,"text/xml");

   }
   else // Internet Explorer
    {
     xmlDoc=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLDOM");
     xmlDoc.async=false;
     xmlDoc.loadXML(txt);
    }

x=xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("paper"); 
for (var i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {  
    var athor =x[i].childNodes[0].firstChild.nodeValue;
    var title = x[i].childNodes[1].firstChild.nodeValue;
    var path = x[i].childNodes[2].firstChild.nodeValue;
    var tack =x[i].childNodes[3].firstChild.nodeValue;
    //do something with these values...
    //each iteration gives one paper details    
    var xml=document.getElementById("element_id");//<div id="element_id"></div>
    var li = document.createElement("br");// create a new <br>  
    newlink = document.createElement('A'); // creating an <a> element
    newlink.innerHTML = athor;// adding <a>athor value here</a>
    newlink.setAttribute('href', path);// <a href="path"></a>

    newlink.appendChild(li);// <a href="path">athor</a><br>
    document.getElementById("element_id").appendChild(newlink);
//finaly it becomes <div id="element_id"><a href="path">athor</a><br></div>


}
```

i posted this answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45676221/5706413)

Answer (score 0):

Add

```
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest(); 
    xhr.open("GET", "/example/xdom/books.xml", false); 
    xhr.send(null); 
    xmlDoc = xhr.responseXML.documentElement; 
    return xmlDoc;
```

in `catch` statement. Like below:

```
function loadXMLDoc(dname) {
  var xmlDoc

  // Internet Explorer
  try {
    xmlDoc = new ActiveXObject('Microsoft.XMLDOM')
  }
  catch (e) {
    // Firefox, Opera, etc.
    try {
      xmlDoc = document.implementation.createDocument('', '', null)
    }
    catch (e) {
      alert(e.message)
    }
  }

  try {
    xmlDoc.async = false
    xmlDoc.load(dname)
    return xmlDoc
  }
  catch (e) {
    //alert(e.message)
    // For Chrome 
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest(); 
    xhr.open("GET", "/example/xdom/books.xml", false); 
    xhr.send(null); 
    xmlDoc = xhr.responseXML.documentElement; 
    return xmlDoc;
  }

  return null
}
```