# XMLDOM "undefined is not a function" alert Chrome

Tags: javascript, xml, google-chrome, dom

I tried to open my XML file but Chrome gives me only an alert saying "Undefined is not a function" and nothing more. I don't know what is the problem. Can you please tell me what is the problem and how can I solve it?

My code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>

<script>
function loadXMLDoc(dname) 
{
try //Internet Explorer
  {
  xmlDoc=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLDOM");
  }
catch(e)
  {
  try //Firefox, Mozilla, Opera, etc.
    {
    xmlDoc=document.implementation.createDocument("","",null);
    }
  catch(e) {alert(e.message)}
  }
try 
  {
  xmlDoc.async=false;
  xmlDoc.load(dname);
  return(xmlDoc);
  }
catch(e) {alert(e.message)}
return(null);
}


var xmldoc= loadXMLDoc('skoly.xml');

</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18442167

Answer (score -1):

Your document.implementation.createDocument is invalid. Here is some documentation on it: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DOMImplementation.createDocument

Comment: Sorry but i still did't get it. When I have xmlDoc=document.implementation.createDocument(null,"xml",null); it still gives me that alert, can add some extra detail to your answer pls?

Comment: Please try and provide some sample code and an explanation in your answer and not just a link to the docs. Links can be broken through time and thereby become irrelevant and as SO is meant to answer questions that are not only relevant to the asker but provide an FAQ of sorts to future users, I'd recommend editing your answer to include such things.