# xml ticker not working in Google Chrome

Tags: javascript, css, xml, google-chrome

I'm using [this script](http://www.dynamicdrive.com/dynamicindex2/xmlticker2.htm) since years in an old website. Now it's no more working with Google Chrome, but it's ok with Firefox and IE.

If you open that site, you'll see a yellow box. With Firefox and IE it's populated with strings or images scrolling, while with Chrome it remains empty. Can anyone explain why?

Answer (score 0):

see https://stackoverflow.com/a/18444795/420006

`.load` doesn't appear to be valid in Chrome