# How to read xml file in javascript

Tags: javascript, xml

I have made a dialog which gets path of xml file and read content of xml file in a string.
i have a variable called output which stires all contents of XML file. Now output is a string which contains all xml file contents. Now i want to parse this output

my code for parsing this is as follows:

```
output = e.target.result;
            console.log("file path"); 
            console.log(output);
            /*var xmlDoc=loadXMLDoc(output);
            console.log("XML DOC");
            console.log(xmlDoc);
            */
              myXML= document.all(output).XMLDocument
              console.log(myXML);
```

i am getting error of XMLDocument undefined. How should i parse this xmlstring?

Comment: `document.all`? In 2013?

Comment: http://www.hiteshagrawal.com/javascript/javascript-parsing-xml-in-javascript might help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use xmlSerializer.

```
var xmlText = new XMLSerializer().serializeToString(xml);
var xmlTextNode = document.createTextNode(xmlText);
someDOMobject.appendChild(xmlTextNode);
```

More examples:
[Convert XML to String and append to page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9898698/convert-xml-to-string-and-append-to-page)

Comment: How are you passing the xml, is it a valid xml? Test with a basic one first.